# Close section not entire nav

Tags: jquery, navigation, nav

Hi I have created this nav in jquery but im starting to confuse myself with the process of how the navigation opens and closes. If you go here: http://hutchcreative.co.uk/rod/ you can see a working demo.

If you click on the menu icon (top right) and then onto contact you see the menu icon changes to an X. when you click the X i would like it to just close the contact section not the entire nav.

I think the main area that needs changing is this section of my jquery:

```
$("#menuIcon").click(function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#contactWrapper').hide();
    $('#menuIcon').removeClass('closeIcon');
    $("#navigationWrapper").removeClass('whiteSection');
    if($('#contactWrapper').is(":visible")) {  $('#contactWrapper').hide(); }
});
```

Here all of my my jquery

```
$('#menuIcon').toggle(function(){
       $('#navigationWrapper ul').hide();
       $('#navigationWrapper ul').show();
       $("#navigationWrapper").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)");
},function(){
       $('#navigationWrapper ul').show();
       $('#navigationWrapper ul').hide();
       $("#navigationWrapper").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)");
});

$('#menu-item-59').click(function(){
    if($("#navigationWrapper").hasClass('whiteSection')){
        $('#contactWrapper').show();
        $('#contactWrapper').hide();
        $('#menuIcon').removeClass('closeIcon');
        $("#navigationWrapper").removeClass('whiteSection');
        $("#navigationWrapper").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)");
    }else{
        $('#contactWrapper').hide();
        $('#contactWrapper').show();
        $("#navigationWrapper").addClass('whiteSection');
        $('#menuIcon').addClass('closeIcon');
        $("#navigationWrapper").css("background-color", "rgba(255,255,255,1)");
    }
});

$("#menuIcon").click(function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#contactWrapper').hide();
    $('#menuIcon').removeClass('closeIcon');
    $("#navigationWrapper").removeClass('whiteSection');
    if($('#contactWrapper').is(":visible")) {  $('#contactWrapper').hide(); }
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<nav id="navigationWrapper" class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span5">
                <div id="logo"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="span7">
                <div id="menuIcon"></div>
                <ul>

                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => 'menu', 'depth' => 1, 'fallback_cb' => '', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) ); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'part', 'social' ); ?>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="contactWrapper" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
                    // query for the about page
                    $your_query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=contact' );
                    // "loop" through query (even though it's just one page) 
                    while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="span12">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span6">
                            <h4><?php the_field('sub_heading'); ?></h4>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div  class="span5 offset1">
                            <div id="emailAdd">
                                <a href="mailto:<?php the_field('email_address'); ?>"><?php the_field('email_address'); ?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="phoneAdd">
                                <?php the_field('phone_number'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                <?php endwhile;
                // reset post data (important!)
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you hide and immediately show some elements again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a toggle click event handler for the #menuIcon that closes the navigation wrapper; perhaps you can check for the closeIcon class and don't close it if exists:

```
$('#menuIcon').toggle(function(){
   $('#navigationWrapper ul').hide();
   $('#navigationWrapper ul').show();
   $("#navigationWrapper").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)");
 },function(){
 if (!$(this).hasClass('closeIcon')) {
   $('#navigationWrapper ul').show();
   $('#navigationWrapper ul').hide();
   $("#navigationWrapper").css("background-color", "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)");
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks that sort of worked, its no longer closing the whole nav, but it is leaving the background white on the nav when the contact section is closed. Im not sure which section I need change to force it to go back to the darks?  You can see the demo on the live version again. thanks!